# Java callback in kotlin is never called

Tags: java, android, azure, kotlin, callback

I'm trying to connect to Azure DPS and Azure IoT hub using this example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java

I'm developing an Android app using Kotlin. I copied the code from the link and and wrote a simple service to test:

```
import android.util.Log
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceClient
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.IotHubClientProtocol
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.IotHubEventCallback
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.Message
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.*
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.internal.exceptions.ProvisioningDeviceClientException
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.security.hsm.SecurityProviderX509Cert
import java.io.IOException


class DPSService(private val idScope: String,
                 private val globalEndpoint: String,
                 private val leafPublicPem: String,
                 private val leafPrivateKey: String,
                 private val intermediateCert: String) : ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationCallback
{
    private val MAX_TIME_TO_WAIT_FOR_REGISTRATION: Long = 20000L
    private val PROVISIONING_DEVICE_CLIENT_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL: ProvisioningDeviceClientTransportProtocol = ProvisioningDeviceClientTransportProtocol.HTTPS
    private val signerCertificates: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(intermediateCert)
    private var provisioningDeviceClient: ProvisioningDeviceClient? = null

    fun register() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting...")
        Log.d(TAG, "Beginning setup.")
        try {
            val provisioningStatus = ProvisioningStatus()
            val securityProvider = SecurityProviderX509Cert(leafPublicPem, leafPrivateKey, signerCertificates)
            provisioningDeviceClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.create(globalEndpoint,
                    idScope,
                    PROVISIONING_DEVICE_CLIENT_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL,
                    securityProvider)
            provisioningDeviceClient?.registerDevice(ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationCallbackImpl(provisioningDeviceClient!!), provisioningStatus)

            while (provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.provisioningDeviceClientStatus != ProvisioningDeviceClientStatus.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_STATUS_ASSIGNED) {
                if (provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.provisioningDeviceClientStatus == ProvisioningDeviceClientStatus.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_STATUS_ERROR ||
                        provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.provisioningDeviceClientStatus == ProvisioningDeviceClientStatus.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_STATUS_DISABLED ||
                        provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.provisioningDeviceClientStatus == ProvisioningDeviceClientStatus.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_STATUS_FAILED ) {
                    provisioningStatus.exception?.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Registration error, bailing out");
                    break;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for Provisioning Service to register");
                Thread.sleep(MAX_TIME_TO_WAIT_FOR_REGISTRATION);
            }

            if (provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.provisioningDeviceClientStatus == ProvisioningDeviceClientStatus.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_STATUS_ASSIGNED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IotHUb Uri : " + provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.iothubUri);
                Log.d(TAG, "Device ID : " + provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.deviceId);

                val iotHubUri = provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.iothubUri
                val deviceId = provisioningStatus.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.deviceId
                var deviceClient: DeviceClient? = null

                try {
                    deviceClient = DeviceClient.createFromSecurityProvider(iotHubUri, deviceId, securityProvider, IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT)
                    deviceClient.open()
                    val messageToSendFromDeviceToHub = Message("Whatever message you would like to send")
                    val callback = IotHubEventCallback { responseStatus, callbackContext -> Log.d(TAG, "Message received! Response status: $responseStatus") }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sending message from provisioned device...")
                    deviceClient.sendEventAsync(messageToSendFromDeviceToHub, callback, null)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Device client threw an exception: " + e.message)
                    deviceClient?.closeNow()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: ProvisioningDeviceClientException) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Provisioning Device Client threw an exception" + e.message)
            provisioningDeviceClient?.closeNow()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Provisioning Device Client threw an exception" + e.message)
            provisioningDeviceClient?.closeNow()
        }

        provisioningDeviceClient!!.closeNow()
    }

    internal class ProvisioningStatus {
        var provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient: ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationResult = ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationResult()
        var exception: Exception? = null
    }

    internal class ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationCallbackImpl(private val provisioningDeviceClient: ProvisioningDeviceClient) : ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationCallback {

        override fun run(provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationResult: ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationResult, exception: java.lang.Exception, context: Any) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationCallback!")
            if (context is ProvisioningStatus) {
                Log.d(TAG, "context is ProvisioningStatus")

                context.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient =
                    provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationResult
                context.exception = exception

                Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    context.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.provisioningDeviceClientStatus.name
                )
                if (context.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.provisioningDeviceClientStatus == ProvisioningDeviceClientStatus.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_STATUS_ASSIGNED) {
                    provisioningDeviceClient?.closeNow()

                    Log.d(
                        TAG,
                        "IotHUb Uri : " + context.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.iothubUri
                    )
                    Log.d(
                        TAG,
                        "Device ID : " + context.provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationInfoClient.deviceId
                    )
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Registration failed")
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Received unknown context")
            }
        }
    }
    
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "DPSService"
    }
}
```

I can see that a registration has happened in the Azure DPS, but the callback doesn't seem to be called on the client side.

I was able to debug and put a breakpoint into the code that calls the callback, and it is running on an other thread than the one that calls the `registerDevice` function.

I use the microsoft libraries from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot